# Shell base64 decode to bytes file

Tags: c#, bash, base64

i'm trying to decode a string and save it into a file following this [method](https://dev.to/_hs_/apache-pulsar-oauth2-dev-setup-with-docker-and-keycloak-k64#:%7E:text=Now%20copy%20that%20value%20and%20somehow%20convert%20it%20to%20bytes%20and%20store%20as%20file.)

C# code working successfully:

```
string val;
var path = @"decoded.txt";

Console.Write("Enter value:");
val = Console.ReadLine();

byte[] bytes1 = Convert.FromBase64String(val);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes1);
```

but i dont get the same result using bash:

```
echo -n realm_result.json.public_key | base64 -di > temp_key_public
```

**EDIT**

the working bash mlethod:

```
printf '%s' {{ realm_result.json.public_key }} | base64 -d > temp_key_public
```

thank you @konrad-rudolph for pointing to the type of variable, it is an ansible task result containing a string.

Comment: Please show both results in your question.

Comment: `base64 -d` attempts to **decode** a Base64-encoded string, but your input isn't a Base64 string! And you should probably not specify the `-i` flag, since it was hiding the error message you were getting explaining this. You probably didn't intend to use the literal string `"realm_result.json.public_key"` as input. It's unclear whether that's a filename (in which case you need to redirect this file into `base64` via `<` instead of using `echo -n … |`) or something else.

Comment: Since the question didn't mention Ansible at all, it wasn't possible to answer, since in just Bash, the solution would produce garbage. Bash doesn't know about templating.